# How to change button color and after a delay

Tags: html, button, delay

When I click the button on my webpage, I'd like that button to change color to red, and after a specific time period, the button has to change to green. This way the visitors can easily see which button is active again so they can click it again and again.

Example: http://www.faucetworld.org/dogerotator.html

When you click the green button on the right side, that button changes the color for a specific time of period and then it become green again.

Comment: please offer any solutions you've already tried or any code you've already used

Comment: at least show us the code you have written so far: the html structure of the page and the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using javascript, the setTimeout method is what you want